# Remotely control a computer and display on remote computer

Tags: windows

I have a desktop with Windows server 2008 and I want to be able to remote in to my desktop from my laptop and control it, but still display on the desktop monitor (as well as laptop monitor). I know I can accomplish this with some VNC, but is there some way to accomplish this using remote desktop connection or any other standard features of windows server 2008 r2?
Thanks!!

Comment: Not that I know of - but this belongs on superuser not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with Remote Desktop Connection/Protocol. However, sharing display on both systems is possible using other tools like Remote Assistance and Desktop Sharing (via Net Meeting).
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457004.aspx 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233175

Answer (score 0):

Previous poster is correct, this is not possible with stock windows [remote control software](http://www.proxynetworks.com). It is, however, possible with proxy networks software, as well as a long list of similar sofware, such a logmein. Proxy is linked to above.